# Adding write permission to SFTP folder stops ability to connect using Filezilla

Tags: 14.04, permissions, chmod, sftp, filezilla

I have followed these instruction to setup a SFTP server on an Ubuntu EC2 instance

https://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/setting-up-an-sftp-site-on-amazon-web-services-ec2-creating-an-account-to-share-with-a-third-party-and-restricting-that-account-to-allow-only-sftp/

But When I connect using filezilla using a keyfile I don't have write permission to the remote folder. If I add write permission for the group the user is in (chmod 775 Files) then I can add and remove files but if I disconnect I am unable to reconnect and get this error in Filezilla.

> Error: Network error: Software caused connection abort
>
> Error: Could not connect to server

In my /etc/ssh/sshd_config I have this line

```
ChrootDirectory /home/%u/Files
```

Here is what I do on the command line:

```
chmod 775 /home/christian/Files
```

After this I cant connect from Filezilla but if already connected can write to Files folder

If I do this instead:

```
chmod 755 /home/christian/Files
```

I can connect from Filezilla but cant write to Files folder.

How is it possible that adding write permission to the Files folder causes connection problems and what do I need to do to be able to connect and write to the server?

Comment: Just so I'm clear are you attempting to use filezilla with the same account you restricted to using read-only ftp?

Comment: It looks like you didn't *exactly* follow that guide - in particular, you made the `ChrootDirectory` a *subdirectory of* `/home/%u` - my knowledge of SFTP jails is sketchy, but doesn't that mean `/home/christian` needs to be owned by `root`? Also, as noted in the comments the installation of `vsftpd` is redundant (it provides FTPS, not SFTP) - not sure how much I'd trust a guide that confuses that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to SFTP connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674861/failed-to-sftp-connection)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not sure that is a duplicate. Sure it mentions that _All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group. After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory._ but that is the case where I have used chmod 755 to take write permission away from the group and left it on root which is the owner. This then leaves it in a state where anyone in the group cant write to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was actually easy to solve. I made a sub folder in Files and changed ownership to root:mygroup then added write permission for the group