# Trying to setup a SFTP user with limited access

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, users, sftp

I was hoping someone could help me with this problem

"Trying to setup a SFTP user with limited access."

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 on a DigitalOcean server. I've posted this on the [DigitalOcean forums](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/trying-to-setup-a-sftp-user-with-limited-access) too.

### Current setup

- I've setup my server using ServerPilot.
- The `system user` is called `serverpilot`
- `serverpilot` has root privileges,
- The `home` folder is located at: `/srv/users/serverpilot`
- The `public` folder is located at: `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/`

### What I want to do

I want to add a second user, but restrict what the user can do:

- Only access a single folder called `newsletters`, it will be in the `public` folder.
- The user needs to be able to upload, delete and rename files via SFTP
- The user must not be able to navigate away from the `newsletters`, folder

This is the full path to the `newsletters` folder:
 `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/newsletters`

### What I've done so far

I've followed this guide [How do I restrict a user to a specific directory?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-restrict-a-user-to-a-specific-directory) by Maxamilian Demian (@Maxoplata), there's a great reply by Jonathan Tittle (@jtittle).

However, I'm still having problems logging in via `SFTP`

I've listed out all the steps I've done - hopefully someone with more experience will be able to spot my error(s)!

### 1. Created a new user

1. Logged in as `root`
2. Created a new user called `user-sftp-only`
3. `adduser user-sftp-only`
4. I can check the **user** has been created by running
5. `compgen -u`
6. `user-sftp-only` is at the bottom of the list
7. I can also see what the path of the user is and shell access by running:
8. `grep user-sftp-only /etc/passwd` outputs:

   ```
   user-sftp-only:x:1004:1007:,,,:/home/user-sftp-only:/bin/bash
   ```

### 2. Give new user root privileges

6. Give new user `user-sftp-only` root privileges
7. `gpasswd -a user-sftp-only sudo`
8. Logout as `root`

### 3. Create a new directory

1. Logged in as `user-sftp-only`
2. Create a new directory in `public` called `newsletters`:
3. `cd /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/`
4. Followed by:
5. `sudo mkdir newsletters`

### 4. Check directory permissions

Still inside the `public` folder from the previous step,  I run

```
$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 serverpilot serverpilot 4096 Mar  7 15:26 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 serverpilot serverpilot 4096 Mar  3 16:22 ..
-rw-r--r--+ 1 serverpilot serverpilot 3393 Mar  3 16:22 index.php
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 root        root        4096 Mar  7 15:26 newsletters
```

From reading various DigitalOcean posts, I know I need to create a group and assign my new user `user-sftp-only` to that group, Then change `root root` to the name of my user and group.

### 5. Create a new group

1. Logged in as `user-sftp-only`
2. `sudo groupadd group-sftp-only`
3. I can check the **group** has been created by running
4. `compgen -g`
5. `group-sftp-only` is at the bottom of the list

**Note:** *I notice my new user called `user-sftp-only` is also in this list?*

### 6. Add user to the group

1. Logged in as `root`
2. Added the user `user-sftp-only` to a group called `group-sftp-only`
3. Doing this means it's no longer possible to SSH in as user `user-sftp-only`

   ```
   usermod -g group-sftp-only -d /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/newsletters -s /sbin/nologin user-sftp-only
   ```

   - `-g`specifies the group name
   - `-d` specifies the users home directory
   - `-s` specifies shell access (/sbin/nologin means SSH is disabled for this user)

### 7. Verify the changes to the user

Logged in as `root`

```
$ grep user-sftp-only /etc/passwd
user-sftp-only:x:1001:1004:,,,:/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/newsletters:/sbin/nologin
```

### 8. Modify SSH Configuration to allow SFTP

1. Logged in as `root`
2. `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
3. Commented out this line:
4. `#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -l INFO`
5. At the **very bottom** of `sshd_config` added this:

   ```
    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
       Match group group-sftp-only
       ChrootDirectory %h
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
   ```

### 9. Restart SSH

1. Still logged in as `root`
2. `service ssh restart`

### 10. Modify permissions

1. Still logged in as `root`
2. This is the home directory for user `user-sftp-only`
3. `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/newsletters`
4. Used this to make sure the home directory is owned by the user and group

   ```
   chown -R user-sftp-only:group-sftp-only /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/newsletters
   ```

### 11. Verify ownership change

Still logged in as `root`:

```
$ cd /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/`
$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 serverpilot    serverpilot     4096 Mar  7 15:26 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 serverpilot    serverpilot     4096 Mar  3 16:22 ..
-rw-r--r--+ 1 serverpilot    serverpilot     3393 Mar  3 16:22 index.php
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 user-sftp-only group-sftp-only 4096 Mar  7 15:26 newsletters

$ cd /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/test-app/public/newsletters
$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 user-sftp-only group-sftp-only 4096 Mar  7 15:26 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 serverpilot    serverpilot     4096 Mar  7 15:26 ..
```

---

That's where I'm up to. However, I can't login in as my new user `user-sftp-only` via `SFTP`

Comment: Nothing interesting in the log? Try adding AllowUsers user-sftp-only to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and bounce sshd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to SFTP connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674861/failed-to-sftp-connection)

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Try to sftp into user-sftp-only account
Note success/failure info message

If failure, add the following line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AllowUsers user-sftp-only
```

then run:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```